# How to call a subroutine using a variable that contains the subroutine name

Tags: vba

I'm just learning to write Excel macros and I'm trying to find out if it is possible to call a subroutine that resides in a different module using a variable that contains the subroutine name.  Example;

Name = "subroutinename"
Call module.Name

Thank you in advance.

Brent

Comment: Did you try the solution here? If it worked for you, would appreciate if you mark it as 'answered'. Tks

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Call Application.Run("SubroutineName")
```

You can call any Sub residing in any module of your project using its unique Name

e.g.

```
Sub SubroutineName()
   ' Does something
End Sub
```